# Prove that a finite subset of a metric space has no limit points

Tags: limits, solution-verification, metric-spaces

Im sitting with this exercise, and would like to know if my way of attempting the proof is correct or not. (Note that im using a earlier result of finite subsets in a metric space.)

**My Attempt**

Let $\{x\} \in A \subseteq (X,d)$ result from earlier exercise (any finite subset is closed in metric space, and therefore $A$ is also closed in the metric space X). From the definition of limit points it follows that all limit points of A in X are in $\bar{A}$. Hence we have that $\bar{A} = \{x\}$. Suppose now that $\{x\}$ were a limit points, then if given $\varepsilon > 0 , (B_\varepsilon(x) \backslash \{x\}) \not = \emptyset$.
$\Rightarrow\Leftarrow$ Which is not possible, since if we remove the point itself we will only have the empty set left $\implies$ $\{x\}$ cannot be a limit point and the finite subset has no limit points.

Im not sure if this result shows it for all subsets in a metric space.

Answer (score 2):

It makes no sense to begin with $\{x\}\in A$. If the idea is that $x$ is an arbitrary element of $A$, you should begin with $x\in A$ instead. And then, unless $A=\{x\}$, $\overline A\ne\{x\}$.

Take $x\in A$. Then $\{d(x,a)\mid a\in A\setminus\{x\}\}$ is a finite set of numbers greater than $0$. Take $r=\min\{d(x,a)\mid a\in A\setminus\{x\}\}$. Then $B_r(x)\cap A=\{x\}$, and therefore $x$ is not a limit point of $A$.